# c# how to select test or prod class from config file

Tags: testing, cloud

I have built a cloud project for a month. My problem is that:

I have 2 classes to connect with Ibm web service. First class is the main class and the second one is test class. I put a key-value to appSetting in Config File.

If value in configFile is "TEST", the project will use test class and if value is the "PROD", the project will use main class. When I change the value in config, I will not change everywhere.

My Manager gave me advice to use "interface" but I didn't understand.

How can I solve this problem basiclly?

Comment: Is it C# or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Both your test class and prod class could implement the said interface. If you need to use the approach where you do the selection in the config file of which class to use you are probably better off creating a data factory class that returns the correct implementation of the interface. The data factory reads the config file and depending on the value in app settings returns the correct class that implements the interface.

Example of doing this in C# (the concept is the same in other oo languages as well):

From the calling class:

`SomethingFactory factory = new SomethingFactory();
ISomething testOrProdObj = factory.GetCorrectImplementation();
var result = testOrProdObj.MyMethod();`

And in the factory class:

`public class SomethingFactory
{
public ISomething GetCorrectImplementation()
{
//Do a check in appsettings to decide which class (TESTSomething or PRODSomething) to instantiate and return
}
}`

Implementation of the interface

`public class TESTSomething : ISomething`

or

`public class PRODSomething : ISomething`